# Why this PL/SQL doesn't work?

Tags: plsql, sqlplus

Im trying to learn PL/SQL. I am struck with this code. Please notify me where im going wrong. I use Oracle 10g in a command line .

```
declare
grade char(1):='&v_grade';
app varchar(15);
begin
app:=case v_grade
when 'a' then
dbms_output.put_line('Excellent');
when 'b' then
dbms_output.put_line('Good');
else
dbms_output.put_line('Bad');
end case;
dbms_output.put_line('Grade'||grade||' Appraisal:'||app);
end;
/
```

It shows

```
Enter value for v_grade: a
old   2: grade char(1):='&v_grade';
new   2: grade char(1):='a';
dbms_output.put_line('Excellent');
                                 *
ERROR at line 7:
ORA-06550: line 7, column 34:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:
. ( * % & = - + < / > at else end in is mod remainder not rem
when <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like
LIKE2_ LIKE4_ LIKEC_ between || multiset member SUBMULTISET_
The symbol ";" was ignored.
ORA-06550: line 9, column 29:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:
. ( * % & = - + < / > at else end in is mod remainder not rem
when <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like
LIKE2_ LIKE4_ LIKEC_ between ||
ORA-06550: line 11, column 28:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol ";" when expecting one of the following:
. ( * % & = - + < / > at end in is mod remainder not rem
<an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like LIKE2_
LIKE4_ LIKEC_ between || multiset
```

please notify me where i am going wrong.

Comment: I know nothing about PL/SQL but I would suspect that since the `put_line` is within a `case...when...then` putting a `;` after it is incorrect. In SQL, `;` terminates statements. You don't want to terminate the statement there. The statement doesn't end until after the `end case` (and you do have a `;` there, which is appropriate).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

T.J. Crowder is sort of right, you shouldn't have a semicolon within a case statement in SQL, but this is the PL/SQL version so it's slightly different.

You are currently trying to assign the (non-existent) return from the `dbms_output.put_line` procedure (not function) call to your `app` variable.

For the assignment to work you need the `case` to evaluate to a string, so you can just use text literals; but the assignment needs to be in each branch:

```
declare
  grade char(1):='&v_grade';
  app varchar(15);
begin
  case grade
    when 'a' then app:= 'Excellent';
    when 'b' then app:= 'Good';
    else app := 'Bad';
  end case;

  dbms_output.put_line('Grade '||grade||' Appraisal: '||app);
end;
/
```

Which when run gets:

```
Enter value for v_grade: a
Grade b Appraisal: Excellent

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Or use a query to do the assignment, though this is not quite as efficient:

```
declare
  grade char(1):='&v_grade';
  app varchar(15);
begin
  select case grade
    when 'a' then 'Excellent'
    when 'b' then 'Good'
    else 'Bad'
  end case
  into app
  from dual;
  dbms_output.put_line('Grade '||grade||' Appraisal: '||app);
end;
/

Enter value for v_grade: b
Grade b Appraisal: Good

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

Or you can do the output directly in each branch:

```
declare
  grade char(1):='&v_grade';
begin
  dbms_output.put('Grade '||grade||' Appraisal: ');
  case grade
    when 'a' then
      dbms_output.put_line('Excellent');
    when 'b' then
      dbms_output.put_line('Good');
    else
       dbms_output.put_line('Bad');
  end case;
end;
/

Enter value for v_grade: c
Grade c Appraisal: Bad

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

The first part of your output is before the case now.

You're basically mixing up the different approaches.

You might want to change the first line to:

```
  grade char(1):= upper('&v_grade');
```

... and then make the case look for A,B,C instead of a,b,c - then it won't matter what case the input is in.

You can read more about the PL/SQL `case` statemnt [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/controlstatements.htm#LNPLS00402) and [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/case_statement.htm).

Comment: I suspected that bit about it not having a value, but as I say, I know nothing about PL/SQL, so... :-)

Comment: Im still getting an error at line 9 column 7 
`Enter value for v_grade: a
old   2:   grade char(1):='&v_grade';
new   2:   grade char(1):='a';
  end case;
      *
ERROR at line 9:
ORA-06550: line 9, column 7:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "CASE" when expecting one of the following:
* & = - + ; < / > at in is mod remainder not rem
<an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like LIKE2_
LIKE4_ LIKEC_ between || multiset member SUBMULTISET_
The symbol "CASE" was ignored.
`

Comment: @AravindS - yes, sorry, I was carrying on your assignment and hadn't registered that you can't do that. I've updated with three alternatives.

Comment: Turns out you can do the assignment [like this too](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36648713/266304).