# PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting + & = etc

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g, pls-00103

This is my code:

```
DECLARE 
v_grade CHAR(1) := UPPER('&grade');
appraisal VARCHAR(20);
BEGIN
appraisal := CASE v_grade
WHEN 'A' THEN 'Excellent'
WHEN 'B' THEN 'Very Good'
WHEN 'C' THEN 'Good'
WHEN 'No such grade'
END;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Grade: '||v_grade||'Appraisal '||appraisal);
END;
/
```

this is the full error code:

```
ERROR at line 10:
ORA-06550: line 10, column 1:
PLS-00103: Encountered the symbol "END" when expecting one of the following:
 * & = - + < / > at in is mod remainer not rem then
 <an exponent (**)> <> or != or ~= >= <= <> and or like like2
 like4 between || multiset member submultiset.
```

I'm learning PL/SQL and I was trying an example from my book but it seems I did something wrong, please don't just give the answer I want to know how you troubleshooted this and how I did make the mistake.

Comment: use else instead when in the line WHEN 'No such grade'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your final clause should use `ELSE` instead of `WHEN`:

```
DECLARE 
  v_grade CHAR(1) := 'C';
  appraisal VARCHAR(20);
BEGIN
  appraisal := 
    CASE v_grade
      WHEN 'A' THEN 'Excellent'
      WHEN 'B' THEN 'Very Good'
      WHEN 'C' THEN 'Good'
      ELSE  'No such grade'
    END;
  DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Grade: '||v_grade||', Appraisal '||appraisal);
END;
```

**UPDATE**

Giving you advice on how to troubleshoot this isn't easy (since it's largely a matter of personal preference); things I usually try are

- narrow down the example (in your case, get rid of all additional clauses in the `CASE`)
- rewrite the offending part of the query from scratch
- copy a similary query that works and change that query gradually to resemble the offending query until I encounter the error

Comment: Interesting, [I didn't think you could do that](http://stackoverflow.com/a/36515682/266304), but it works on 11g too. Always good to learn... *8-)

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite code like this

```
DECLARE 
v_grade CHAR(30) := UPPER('&grade');
appraisal VARCHAR(20);
BEGIN
appraisal := CASE v_grade
WHEN 'A' THEN 'Excellent'
WHEN 'B' THEN 'Very Good'
WHEN 'C' THEN 'Good'
ELSE 'No such grade'
END;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Grade: '||v_grade||'Appraisal '||appraisal);
END;
```